# Decode unicode string from json column in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, decode

I have a json column on mysql that contains values like:

```
{"value_1": "Cancu00fan", "value_2":"Other value"}
```

I'm trying to get the value_1 property I require that value decoded ("Cancún"), I'm doing this:

```
SELECT convert(json_field->>"$.value_1" USING latin1) FROM example_table;
```

but I'm still getting:

```
"Cancu00fan"
```

When I do the insert of the data, I insert the data as:

```
 {"value_1": "Cancún", "value_2":"Other value"}
```

But MySQL encode it automatically, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

not what I would like but works for me

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `convertunicode`(encoded varchar(100))
    RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8mb4
    BEGIN
        DECLARE decoded VARCHAR(20);
        SET decoded = encoded;
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00e1", "á");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00e9", "é");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00ed", "í");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00f3", "ó");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00fa", "ú");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00c1", "Á");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00c9", "É");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00cd", "Í");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00d3", "Ó");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00da", "Ú");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00f1", "ñ");
        SET decoded = replace(decoded, "u00d1", "Ñ");
    RETURN decoded;
    END
```